# The specified test name is not valid. The name cannot be empty

Tags: vbscript, qtp

```
Set qtApp = CreateObject("QuickTest.Application") ' Create the Application object
qtApp.Launch ' Start QuickTest
qtApp.Visible = True ' Make the QuickTest application visible

' Make changes in a test on Quality Center with version control
qtApp.TDConnection.Connect "http://alm11.ca.com/qcbin", "MFSO", "CA_Gen_QA", "kumbh05", "Bharat037*", True ' Connect to Quality Center

If qtApp.TDConnection.IsConnected Then ' checking condition
  Set qtResult = CreateObject("QuickTest.RunResultsOptions") 'Object created
  qtResult.ResultsLocation = "D:\Temp\" ' My results location
  qtApp.Open "[ALM] ' Subject\MASTER_SCRIPTS\ARTS85\REGRESSION\DISTRIBUTED\INST_EXEC\WIN_ASP\bharath_Test", True ' Open the test
  Set objTest = qtApp.Test 'Object test
  objTest.Run qtResult ' Running the script
  objTest.SaveAs "D:\Temp\" ' I am getting ERROR MESSAGE HERE 
  qtResult.ResultsLocation = "D:\Temp\" ' Set the results location
End If ' If CLOSED

qtApp.TDConnection.Disconnect 'Disconnecting 
qtApp.Quit 'quit
Set qtApp = Nothing 'object set to nothing
```

In `SaveAs` method I am getting error as

> The specified test name is not valid. The name cannot be empty.

Answer (score 3):

Your:

```
objTest.SaveAs "D:\Temp\" ' I am getting ERROR MESSAGE HERE 
qtResult.ResultsLocation = "D:\Temp\" ' Set the results location
```

indicates that "D:\Temp\" is a folder. Add a file name.

Answer (score 0):

SaveAs method should take a file name and not a folder name.

You must provide filename to that function

Remove

`objTest.SaveAs "D:\Temp\"`

Try this:

```
objTest.SaveAs "D:\Temp\testname"
```

Comment: but It will return folders and XML file also .